# Gorgeous diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to find all integer solutions of the following equation?
$$y^7=14 \cdot 3^{100}x^6 + 70 \cdot 3^{300} x^4 + 42 \cdot 3^{500} x^2 + 2 \cdot 3^{700}$$

Comment: One question : Why this one?

Comment: I found this problem in the ancient unnamed academic tutorial about the number theory. And I can't let go...

Comment: $x = 3^{100}, \; \; y = 2 \cdot 3^{100}$ works

Comment: You can make progress by considering divisibility by powers of $3$ on both sides and working back and forth. I haven't followed it through to see where it gets you, but it may imply that the LHS is divisible by $3^{100}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $x=3^{100} a$ to balance all those large powers of 3:

$$ y^7 = 2\cdot 3^{700} \left( 7a^6 + 35a^4 + 21a^2 + 1 \right) $$

Due to the common factor, $y$ should be of the form $y=2\cdot 3^{100} b$:

\begin{align}
64 b^7 &= 7a^6 + 35a^4 + 21a^2 + 1 \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^3 \binom7{2k} a^{2k} \\
&= \frac{(1+a)^7 + (1-a)^7}2 \\
(2b)^7 &= (1+a)^7 + (1-a)^7
\end{align}

The last equation only allows solutions of the form $a=\pm 1,b=1$, so two sets of solutions are:

$$ x = \pm3^{100},\quad y = 2\cdot 3^{100} $$

---

We don't really need to assume $3^{100}\mid x$. Following the idea above original equation can be rewritten as

\begin{align} 
y^7 &= 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^3 \binom{7}{2k} 3^{100(7-2k)}x^{2k} \\
 &= (3^{100} - x)^7 + (3^{100} + x)^7
\end{align}

which does not have any integer solutions except $x=\pm 3^{100}$ (Fermat's last theorem, $n=7$). So the above two are the only solutions.

Comment: The equation can be written  $y^7=(3^{100}+x)^7+(3^{100}-x)^7$. So ur answer is true.